Convert a HashMap into a List<String> which joins both key and value using String.format with a Java stream
How to do this:
int size = ...
var a = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : myHashMap) {      
  a.add( String.format("%s %.3f", e.getKey(), 100.0 * e.getValue() / size));
}

using Stream?
int size = ...
var a = myHashMap.entrySet()     
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
  .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
  .toList();

How to both getValue and getKey and combine them using String.format ?

Just change .map(Map.Entry::getValue) to .map(e -> String.format(...))? This seems a bit too obvious...

If you're formatting, you need to double up for a percent sign: map(e ->String.format("%s %.3f%%", e.getKey(), 100.0 * e.getValue())).toList();

@g00se I don't need a percent sign.

Right. By stating % Value I thought you did

Note that toList returns a List, but not an ArrayList specifically.  Assuming you don't actually care about the return type, I'd adjust the title of this question.

This can be achieved by using a lambda expression (e -> String.format(...)) instead of a method reference expression (Map.Entry::getValue).
int size = ...
var a = myHashMap.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
  .map(e -> String.format("%s %.3f", e.getKey(), 100.0 * e.getValue() / size))
  .toList();

Thanks to @Sweeper for this approach.
It's always obvious once you've figured out the answer.

I've added a little extra descriptive context to your answer
